# С# как прочитать и записать большой exe файл

Tags: c#, exe, запись

Все мучаюсь над чтением и записью больших exe файлов, нужно чтоб программа читала большой exe файл и меняла в нем некоторые символы после чего записывала во 2 файл, пытался реализовать так

```
int n = 0;
string a = "•";
string b = "¤";
string c = "¶";
string d = "_1_";
string s = "_2_";
string f = "_3_";
string[] line = new string[10000000];
line = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Veils\Desktop\test.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251"));

            while (n != 100000)
            {
                try
                {                   
                    line[n] = line[n].Replace(a, d);
                    line[n] = line[n].Replace(b, s);
                    line[n] = line[n].Replace(c, f);
                    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\Veils\Desktop\test1.txt", line[n] + Environment.NewLine, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251"));
                    n++;
                }
                catch (Exception) {  n = 100000; }
            }
```

но это работает только с текстом а для exe файла почему то слетают строки, хотя сам файл копируется полностью кто-нибудь помогите правильно записать файл без ошибки по памяти!

Comment: Начнем с того, что exe - бинарный формат и читать/писать его стоит в бинарном же формате и четко знать, в какие данные и где вы хотите менять, оперируя смещенииями.

Comment: Если exe на с# писаный, а так же в некоторых других случаях, байты защищены от изменений контрольной суммой (иногда подписью), если да - прийдётся перещитать.

Comment: не нужно переписывать exe файл что бы он был рабочий просто нужно прочитать его текст в 1251 кодировке заменить символы и выдать так чтобы при обратной замене получался тот же exe файл а писать в бин код ну извините и долго и размер большой думал получится как текст, а он странно линии перераспределяет